# Disable LaTeX concealing in nvim easymotion highlighting

Tags: vim, latex, neovim

When using nvim with vim-easymotion it conceals a lot of LaTeX commands while showing all the easymotion symbols, i.e. it shows unicode symbols as motion symbols which I just can not type. It only shows this in this way during the search. During regular typing there is no concealing.

I already have the conseallevel set to 0.

Can I somehow turn this feature off?

Here is a minimal example:
init.vim

```
set conceallevel=0
" Plugins - Vundle
call plug#begin('~/.config/nvim/bundle')
            "easy motion
            Plug 'easymotion/vim-easymotion'
                let g:EasyMotion_do_mapping = 0 " Disable default mappings

                " Jump to anywhere you want with minimal keystrokes, with just one key binding.
                " `s{char}{label}`
                nmap s <Plug>(easymotion-overwin-f)
                " or
                " `s{char}{char}{label}`
                " Need one more keystroke, but on average, it may be more comfortable.
                nmap s <Plug>(easymotion-overwin-f2)

                " Turn on case-insensitive feature
                let g:EasyMotion_smartcase = 1

                " JK motions: Line motions
                map <Leader>j <Plug>(easymotion-j)
                map <Leader>k <Plug>(easymotion-k)
```

And a LaTeX file to edit

```
\documentclass{article}
                                                                                                
\begin{document}
                                                                                                
This is some test equation
                                                                                                
\[ A \subseteq B \wedge B \subseteq C\implies A \subseteq C, \]
                                                                                                
where $A,B$,and $C$ are sets.
                                                                                                
                                                                                                
\end{document}
```

which looks just fine while editing. But if e.g. I want to jump to the first `\subseteq` by pressing first 's' and then 't,e' is pressed I get displayed

```
\documentclass{article}
                                                                                                
\begin{document}
                                                                                                
This is some gest equation
                                                                                                
 A ⊆d B ∧ B ⊆s C\implies A ⊆a C, 
                                                                                                
where A,B,and C are sets.    
                                                                                                
                                                                                                
\end{document}
```

where all math symbols are highlighted and everything shifts, since the symbols do not need as much space as the LaTeX code for them and often the math symbols even completely overlap with their displayed shortcuts.